# Is there a proven performance difference between joins in Hive on INT/BIGINT versus VARCHAR?

Tags: join, hive, int, varchar, query-performance

For years I have been reading / hearing about the *'performance advantage'* of database joins on **bigint** columns have OVER joins on **(var)char** columns.

Unfortunately, when looking for real answers / advice regarding to *'simlilar type questions'*:

- The examples used are in a *'traditional'* RDBMS context, like Mysql or Oracle / SQL Server. Take for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332300/is-there-a-real-performance-difference-between-int-and-varchar-primary-keys) or [this example](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/02/15/are-int-joins-faster-than-string-joins-2/)
- The answer is quite old and the end-difference in *runtime* is not that great. Again, see [this example](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/02/15/are-int-joins-faster-than-string-joins-2/)

I ***have not seen*** an example using a version of **Hive** (preferably version 1.2.1 or higher) where a large *(BIG-DATA-ISH)* data set (let us say **500 million+ rows**) is joined to an *similar size dataset* on:

1. a Bigint column
2. **VERSUS** a (var)Char(32) column.
3. **VERSUS** a (var)Char(255) column.

I am choosing a size of 32 because it is the size of an MD5 Hash, converted to characters and 255 because it is *'in range'* of the largest Natural Key I have ever seen.

*Futhermore*, I would expect Hive:

- to run under the **Tez** engine
- use an (compressed) file format like **ORC + ZLip / Snappy**

Does anyone know of ***such an example***, substantiated with proof by showing Hive *Explain plans*, CPU, File & network resources + query runtimes?

Comment: My sense is that you could test this as fast as ask us! A data set of a few million (sparse and dense) values would be large enough to show up any difference.

Comment: Good suggestion, however at the time of asking this question I didn't have access to a system where I could really test this.... Now I'm working in Bigquery

Comment: Possible performance difference is negligible because of parallel execution. Too many other factors like cluster load and mapper /reducer parallelism degree are creating too much  measurement uncertainty

Comment: (Opinion)  I/O is the dominant part of the effort.  The datatype is less critical.